# Writing to bucket table involves sorting？

Tags: apache-spark

I have following simple code snippet to exercise spark sql `bucketBy`.

```
    val spark = SparkUtils.spark(nCores = 6)
    val t1 = System.currentTimeMillis()
    spark.range(0, 10000).toDF("id1").write.bucketBy(8, "id1").saveAsTable(s"t_$t1")
```

The plan is as follows:

```
+- WriteFiles                                                                                                                                                   
   +- Sort [pmod(hash(id1#2L, 42), 8) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0                                                                                                
      +- Project [id#0L AS id1#2L]                                                                                                                              
         +- Range (0, 10000, step=1, splits=6)
```

I would ask what `Sort [pmod(hash(id1#2L, 42), 8) ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0` does here .

It is sorting on the mod of hash of id1, **not id1 itself**, is there any sense for this sorting? what's the purpose for the sorting on the mod of hash of id1?

Thanks.